# Write to file with System.cmd :into option in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to make a postgres dump of my database using [`System.cmd/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3) and write the file into the local folder of my phoenix app but I can't make it work. I tried to use "into" option.

Here is what I've done:

```rb
System.cmd("pg_dump", ["myapp_dev"], into: "backup.sql")
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? How does it fail? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:into` option, as it’s clearly stated in [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3-options), does inject the result into a given collectable, meaning the output of the command would be appended to the string you have passed and returned back.

It’s easier to dump to the file using native [`pg_dump --file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) option, letting the shell and `pg_dump` perform all the work and not passing huge blobs back and forth. The below should work.

```rb
System.cmd("pg_dump", ["myapp_dev", "--file=backup.sql"])
```